# How to generate oauth_signature intuit ipp QBO API V3

Tags: c#, oauth, intuit-partner-platform

I am having some issues with limitations of the .NET SDK and so would like to issue my own calls to the API and parse the JSON results. I am stuck on creating the authorization header parameter oauth_signature as outlined [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app/implement_oauth_in_your_app).

For this parameter it states: `Contains the value generated by running all other request parameters and two secret values through a signing algorithm`

1. Does the "two secret values" refer to the OAuthAccessTokenSecret and the consumerSecret?
2. Does "all other request parameters" mean just those parameter values? Concatenated?
3. How do you use 2 secret values in an and HMACSHA1 signing algorithm? All examples I see just use one

What I have so far.

```
public static string GetOAuthAuthorization(string oauthToken, string oauthSecret, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret)
        {   
            string oauth_token = oauthToken;
            string oauth_nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string oauth_consumer_key = consumerKey;
            string oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
            int oauth_timestamp = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
            string oauth_version="1.0";

            string dataString = oauth_token + oauth_nonce + oauth_consumer_key + oauth_timestamp;

            //TODO: use following to create oauth_signature
            byte[] hashkey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(oauthSecret);  //is this one of the secret values?
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString);
            HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(hashkey); 
            byte[] result = hmac.ComputeHash(data);

            string oauth_signature=Convert.ToBase64String(result);

            return string.Format("OAuth oauth_token='{0}',oauth_nonce='{1}',oauth_consumer_key='{2}',oauth_signature_method='{3}',oauth_timestamp='{4}',oauth_version='{5}',oauth_signature='{6}'",
                oauth_token, oauth_nonce, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_signature_method,oauth_timestamp,oauth_version, oauth_signature
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the sample app provided by Intuit for V3. This is already implemented. You can set in your keys and debug-

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/

When you had generated an app with IPP, you must have got a consumer key and consumer secret.
That is what is being referred in the line you have mentioned.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started

For other questions, just debug the sample code after setting in your app keys in web.config, you will get the answers.

Comment: Thanks @nimisha but I don't want to use the SDKs. I am trying to figure out how to make the API calls directly, without using the SDK. So this comes down to making a REST call, which I can do. The problem I am having is figuring out how to populate the specific fields that must be in the Authorization header of the REST call.

Comment: @ChadRichardson Did you ever figure this out?  We are trying to not use the SDK also.

Comment: So Intuit has created an API but can't tell anyone how to generate the signature to make the calls.  It's almost as if no one who works there even knows anymore...